# Images no render in qweb report - Odoo 11

Tags: xml, image, odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I am modifying the report sale.report_saleorder_document for some days I am trying to insert images I have tried the following:

But to date, only shows me small squares, image attached.

Any help will be much appreciate[![enter image description here][1]][1]d

**mp_report_sale_order.xml**

```
<odoo>
<data>
<!-- Inherit quotation report (from module sale) -->
<template id="report_quotation_inherit_mp" 
inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
<xpath expr="//p[@id='fiscal_position_remark']" position="after">

<img class="img img-responsive"  src="/home/odoo/odoo-dev/justin-addons/mp_report_saleorder/src/images/visa.jpeg"/>
<img t-att-src="'/home/odoo/odoo-dev/justin-addons/mp_report_saleorder/src/images/visa.jpeg'" />
<img src="/home/odoo/odoo-dev/justin-addons/mp_report_saleorder/src/images/visa.jpeg"/>
<img class="img" src="/mp_report_saleorder/src/images/visa.jpg"/>

</xpath>

</template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

**__manifest__.py**

```
'depends': ['base','sale'],

'data': [
    'reports/mp_report_sale_order.xml',
],
```

Comment: Could you put exactly what do you set in your report field for the image src value?

Comment: Hello Axel,  I have added the images that I try to insert

Comment: I mean on the report definition. what qweb values are you setting

Comment: Alex, I have added the values.

Comment: `/path_to_image/image.jpeg` doesn't seems to be a proper value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have an idea. Try to do this steps:

1- In the module `mp_report_saleorder` create a folder with name `static`, put you images inside that folder. For example move your module `src/images` folder to `static/src/images`.

2- Restart your Odoo instance so your static folder will be available

3- Set this path in your QWEB template for the images(example path):

```
<img src="/mp_report_saleorder/static/src/images/visa.jpeg"/>
```

Modules static folder are somehow public assets folder to serve content files like css, js, images, less, font, etc

Comment: Happy to help. An upvote to my answer will be a plus. :)